# cocos2d-xでスマホを傾けて遊べるゲームを作りたいです。

Tags: android, ios, cocos2d-x

cocos2d-x 3.8を使って開発しています、
スマホを傾けて遊ぶゲームを作ろうとしています。
２年ほど前からcocos2d-xが用意している
`setAccelerometerEnabled`を使ってみているのですが

どうしても

```
Device::setAccelerometerEnabled(true);
auto accelerationListener
    =  EventListenerAcceleration::create(CC_CALLBACK_2(HelloWorldScene::onAcceleration, this));
getEventDispatcher()->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(accelerationListener, this);

void HelloWorldScene::onAcceleration(Acceleration* acc, Event* event)
{
    (float) accx = acc->x;
    (float) accy = acc->y;
}
```

として使っていると、iPhone 4/5s/6sの実機たちで確認をすると
途中から角度が安定しなくなり、値がおかしくなってしまうバグがあります。

```
Director::getInstance()->pause();
Director::getInstance()->resume();
```

と、一度ポーズをしてから再開すると
値が通常通りに戻ってはくれるのですが、
またしばらくすると角度がおかしくなってしまいます。
ゲーム全体を一度 止めて再開させているので、ゲームの動きに影響があり困っています。

なにか、`setAccelerometerEnabled`だけをポーズさせる方法や
他に良い解決方法などございましたら教えて頂けると幸いです。

よろしくお願いします。